# Create numbered footnote, but no reference in document

Tags: footnotes, ref

I want to create a footnote with a specific number, but with no reference in the text.

The reason is because I am attaching an image in which I've put a footnote citation, but I don't know how to add a footnote now...
If I use something like `\footnote[5]{footnote here}`, then the number 5 shows up... How do i either hide this, or add a footnote with a specific number without a reference?

tl;dr- I have an image with some text and there is footnote citation on the text. I need to add a footnote which doesn't put the ref number anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `\refstepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{bla bla}`
or just with `\footnotetext[3]{bla bla}`. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
foo\refstepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{bla bla} bar baz

foo\footnotetext[5]{bla bla} bar baz
\end{document}
```

Comment: please can you help me in this question : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587984/can-you-help-me-to-correct-this-tex-files-about-chapter-format

Comment: @Vrouvrou did you see my comment there?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can satisfy you. I am still new but I used this code to do exactly that.

```
\makeatletter
\def\nonumfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
your text\nonumfootnote{this footnote has no number}
\end{document}
```