# Can you help me to correct this tex files ? "About chapter format"

Tags: xetex, chapters, polyglossia

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz,enumerate,array,fancyhdr,enumitem,fancybox,graphicx,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[arabic]{minitoc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
%======================================================== 
% languages & fonts===========================================
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Andalus}
%%
%=========================================================
\addto\captionsarabic{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptername}{\sffamily الفصل}%
}
\addto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\sffamily الفصل }}
%===============================================================



\pagestyle{fancy}
\parindent=0pt

\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or الأول
\or الثاني 
\or الثالث 
\or الرابع
\or الخامس
\else
I need more words\fi}
%=======================================
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
%=============================================


\titleformat{\chapter}
{\bfseries\large}
{}
{0pt}
{\titlerule{3pt}~\raisebox{-3.5pt}
{\sc{\chaptername}~
\thechapter}~\Huge\titlerule{3pt}\\
\vspace{1.05cm}\titlerule{}\\
\filcenter #1\\
\vspace{1.25cm}\titlerule}



\begin{document}

\chapter{الرياضيات}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the question? At first glance, you need to load *titlesec* with `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}` and you need to replace `\titlerule{3pt}` with `\titlerule[3pt]`.

Comment: @touhami thank you very much it works

Comment: @touhami please when I do \tableofcontents it appear like chapter 0 , please how to delete "chapter 0" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

First you need to load *titlesc* package with the option *explicit* i.e `\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}`.

Second; the command `\titlerule` has one **optional** argument so one needs to type `\titlerule[3pt]`.

For the question add in comment. One should use the `numberless` variant to define chapter format or a like.

`\titleformat{name=\chapter}...` for numbered chapters.

`\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}...`  for unnumbered chapters.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz,enumerate,array,fancyhdr,enumitem,fancybox,graphicx,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[arabic]{minitoc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
%======================================================== 
% languages & fonts===========================================
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setcounter{minitocdepth}{1}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Andalus}
%%
%=========================================================
\addto\captionsarabic{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptername}{\sffamily الفصل}%
}
\addto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\sffamily الفصل }}
%===============================================================



\pagestyle{fancy}
\parindent=0pt

\newcommand\words[1]{\expandafter\xwords\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\xwords#1{\ifcase#1\or الأول
\or الثاني 
\or الثالث 
\or الرابع
\or الخامس
\else
I need more words\fi}
%=======================================
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\words{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother
%=============================================


\titleformat{name=\chapter}
{\bfseries\large}
{}
{0pt}
{\titlerule[3pt]~\raisebox{-3.5pt}
{\sc{\chaptername}~
\thechapter}~\Huge\titlerule[3pt]\\
\vspace{1.05cm}\titlerule\\
\filcenter #1\\
\vspace{1.25cm}\titlerule}


\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}
{\bfseries\large}
{}
{0pt}
{%
%\titlerule[3pt]\\ %comment or uncomment this
\Huge
%\titlerule[3pt]\\ %comment or uncomment this
\vspace{1.05cm}\titlerule\\
\filcenter #1\\
\vspace{1.25cm}\titlerule}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{الرياضيات}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: you're welcome! :-)